# Как заполнить дату в словаре расписания универсально?

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть вот такое задание:
нужно написать функцию, которая отдает список рейсов по городу отправления, городу назначения и заданной дате (выдает 5 рейсов, ближайших к заданной дате, но только среди будущих — на вчера купить билет нельзя).
хотя бы один рейс должен иметь периодичность по дням недели и хотя бы один по дням месяца. Например, из Москвы в Лондон — по понедельникам и средам в 10:00, а из Лондона в Париж — 10-го и 20-го числа каждого месяца в 15:30.

Хотя бы между одной парой городов не должно быть сообщения

на входе у нас есть дата и города отправления
проблема в том, как составить грамотно словари, так как дата задается пользователем. у меня получается такая структура, но значения у словаря schedule (1,2,3) не являются универсальными и дальше мне не сделать проверку. Вопрос в том, как составить правильно?

```
import datetime


date = '01-01-2021'
list_date = date.split('-')
check_list = [date]
for i in range(2, 6):
    new_date = datetime.date(int(list_date[2]), i, int(list_date[0])).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    check_list.append(new_date)
print(check_list)

cities = ['Лондон', 'Париж', 'Москва']

number_days = [i for i in range(1,32)]


routes = ['Лондон-Париж', 'Лондон-Москва', 'Париж-Лондон', 'Париж-Москва', 'Москва-Лондон']

schedule = {'Лондон-Париж': ({'1': ('10-00', 'GV152')},
                             {'2': ('10-00', 'GV152')},
                             {'3': ('10-00', 'GV152')},
                             {'4': ('10-00', 'GV152')},
                             {'5': ('10-00', 'GV152')},
                             {'6': ('10-00', 'GV152')},
                             {'7': ('10-00', 'GV152')},
                             ),
            'Лондон-Москва': ({'10': ('10-20', 'GV157')},
                              {'20': ('10-20', 'GV157')},
                              ),
            'Париж-Лондон': ({'1': ('10-40', 'GV154')},
                             {'2': ('10-40', 'GV154')},
                             {'3': ('10-40', 'GV154')},
                             {'4': ('10-40', 'GV154')},
                             {'5': ('10-40', 'GV154')},
                             {'6': ('10-40', 'GV154')},
                             {'7': ('10-40', 'GV154')},
                             ),
            'Париж-Москва': ({'1': ('10-10', 'GV155')},
                             {'2': ('10-10', 'GV155')},
                             {'3': ('10-10', 'GV155')},
                             {'4': ('10-10', 'GV155')},
                             {'5': ('10-10', 'GV155')},
                             {'6': ('10-10', 'GV155')},
                             {'7': ('10-10', 'GV155')},
                             ),

            'Москва-Лондон': ({'10': ('10-30', 'GV157')},
                              {'20': ('10-30', 'GV157')},
                              ),
            }
```